# $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^a+x^b}$ or $f(x) = \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p}$?

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $0< a\leq b$, for which values $p$, does the function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^a+x^b}dx$$ belong to $L_p(0,\infty)$?

The first step in the *given* (**potentially incorrectly written**) solution is:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^a+x^b} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} dx$$

Now I can solve the problem if he somehow mistakenly wrote wrong both the question, and the LHS side there, and the problem should actually have been for $f(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} dx$

Does that first step there make sense how he wrote it for some reason that I can't see? Or he dropped the $^p$ twice?

Comment: I would assume he meant to have the $p$th power in the first integral. ( I would also write "the first step in the *given* solution.)

Comment: @zhw. Oh sorry about the phrasing, thanks, I think so too

Answer (score 0):

In the case that he did write it wrong, we obtain the solution as follows:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(x^a+x^b)^p} dx$$
$$= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{ap}(1+x^{b-a})^p} dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{bp}(x^{a-b}+1)^p} dx$$

We know that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^q} dx$ converges if and only if $q<1$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^q}$ covnerges if and only if $q>1$, and hence:

Both integrals converge if and only if: $ap<1$ and $bp>1$ so $$ap<1<bp\implies a\lt \frac1p <b\implies \frac1a> p > \frac1b$$